# ASP.Net MVC 2 partialview that reads part of URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, partial-views

i am creating a partialview with a controller action like:

public ActionResult GetPostsByUser(string userName)
        {

where userName is part of the URL:

www.example.com/User/toddM

toddM being the userName

First off.. am i going about this the right way?? if i make it a querystring ?userName=toddM it works.. but i need it to read from the URL. Again, this is a partialview . thanks!

Comment: Why are you tring to use UserControl inside ASP.NET MVC? You should be using PartialViews.

Comment: sorry wrong nomenclature.. I am using PartialView, replace the word usercontrol with partialview in my original post. thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you're missing a route that matches `/User/{userName}`. Read up on routes. :) Also, whether it's in the query string or the URL makes no functional difference in this case. You should still not extract the user name from the View, but from the Controller.

Comment: hi bzlm that is the info i am looking for. How can i extract the username portion of the URL from within the controller? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Url sample is not "well formed" as it miss one of the controller/action.

In fact, as per the default route created by the MVC project template you should have

```
"{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
```

An URL like `www.example.com/Post/User/toddM` would perfectly fits within the default route and so I think will work without any problem.

This one would be your action in an hypothetical PostController

```
public ActionResult User( string id )
{
    //id will contain toddM 
}
```

Comment: Works! thanks, i had the signature wrong public ActionResult User( string userName )
{ and no matching route. awesome, thanks again!